# Calculating fourier transform of sawtooth function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Let the following $T$-periodic signal :
[image]

then $$\begin{align}F(x(t))(\omega) =& \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(t) \exp(-i\omega t) \mathrm{d}t = \frac{A}{T} \int_{-\infty}^\infty t \exp(-i \omega t) \mathrm{d}t = \frac{A}{T} \int_{-\infty}^\infty i \frac{\partial{\exp(-i \omega t)}}{{\partial \omega}} \mathrm{d}t \\& =\frac{A}{T} i \frac{\partial}{\partial \omega} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-i \omega t) \mathrm{d}t =\frac{A}{T} i \frac{\partial \delta (\omega)}{\partial \omega} = i\frac{A \delta '(\omega) }{T}\end{align}$$
after this how can i find the complex form to find the amplitude and phase spectrums

Comment: Your sawtooth wave function $x(t)=\frac{A}{T}\, (t \bmod T)$ is not the same as $\frac{A}{T}\, t$, I believe you can derive a result from the Fourier transform of the [Fourier series for the sawtooth wave function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html) where the result is an infinite series of [Dirac delta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).